# How to Remove Undirected Edges that are the Same

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Given:

```
theData = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 1}
```

I would like to remove any duplicates where I define a duplicate to be:

```
x <-> y == y <-> x
```

Have tried:

```
theRule = UndirectedEdge[p1_, p2_] :> UndirectedEdge[p2, p1]
DeleteDuplicates[theData, # == (# /. theRule) &]
```

Comment: Bah, DeleteDuplicates[theGraphData, #1 == (#2 /. theRule) &] works. Any other creative ways of doing this?

Comment: I think that would fail for a data set of: {1--2,3--1,2--1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Sort` the elements of `theData`:

   ```
   DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ theData]
   ```

   > ```
   > {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}
   > ```
2. Use a function `ue` with `Attribute` `Orderless`:

   ```
   SetAttributes[ue, Orderless];
   UndirectedEdge @@@ DeleteDuplicates[ue @@@ theData]
   ```

   > ```
   > {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}
   > ```

   or

   ```
   DeleteDuplicates[ue @@@ theData] /. ue -> UndirectedEdge
   ```

   > ```
   > {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}
   > ```
3. Temporarily make `UndirectedEdge` `Orderless`:

   ```
   SetAttributes[UndirectedEdge, Orderless];
   DeleteDuplicates[theData]
   ```

   > ```
   > {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}
   > ```

   Use `ClearAttributes[UndirectedEdge, Orderless]` to reset the `Attributes` of `UndirectedEdge` back to `{Protected, ReadProtected}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your data to a graph and use `SimpleGraph` to get rid of the duplicates.

```
EdgeList@SimpleGraph@Graph@theData
```

> ```
> {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete both true duplicates (i.e. 1<->2 is equal to 1<->2) and those that fulfill your definition of a duplicate you may try

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[theData, Sort]
```

Otherwise you may try

```
DeleteDuplicates[theData, # === Reverse@#2 &]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Union[theData, SameTest -> (#1 === Reverse@#2 &)]
```